# Substituting variables into the gamma function

Tags: integration

I am trying to show that $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2} dx =\sqrt \pi$

I know that $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt \pi$

and also that:

$\Gamma(1/2)=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-t} dt$

Why can I use the substitution $t=x^2$ ? The substitution is not one to one on $t \in[0,\infty) $? Couldn't $x=- \sqrt t$ as well as $x= \sqrt t$ ?

Comment: By parity, $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2}\,dx = 2 \int_0^{+\infty} e^{-x^2}\,dx.$$ Now substitute.

Comment: $\Gamma(1/2) = \int_0^\infty t^{-1/2} e^{-t} dt  =  \int_0^\infty x^{-1} e^{-x^2} 2x dx = 2\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} dx  = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} dx$ with $t = x^2$ and $ e^{-x^2} =  e^{-(-x)^2}$

Comment: @user1952009 Why can you use that method when $t=x^2$ could mean that $t=- \sqrt x$ as well as $t= \sqrt x$

Comment: I do the change of variable $t = x^2$ in the 1st integral, and I don't get what you are asking

Comment: If $t \in [0, \infty)$, $x$ could be negative?

Comment: @user1952009 If $t=x^2$ with $t \in [0, \infty)$, the limits of integration **for** $x$ are not neccesarily $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: so what ? ${}{}{}$ $t = x^2, x = \sqrt{t}$, and $t : 0 \to \infty$ becomes $x : 0 \to \infty$. if you want to consider $x = - \sqrt{t}$ then you get $x : 0 \to - \infty$ but $t^{-1/2}e^{-t} = -x e^{-x^2}$ and the result is (of course) the same